# Hosting Public websites with Django Dev Server

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I am trying to host my personal website, I am new to hosting websites business, so this may be a Noob question.

So I made my website using django, and tested everything locally. Now I want to make the site public, then I came across this :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment
which seemed to be a pain in the arse.

But, Then I figured i could make the website available on all interfaces using:

> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
>   Now I can access the website using  http://myIp/myapp

So my question is, "Is it a good idea to host websites using the django dev server"

The gut feeling is a "No", but I really want to know "Why?"

Comment: To quote [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#runserver): "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache,it's easy, and there are plenty of startup guides with django and apache, even in the django docs.

Answer (score 1):

Your gut feeling is right. You better use a WSGI server that is going to serve your django app. 
It is not that hard to configure.

Personally I like to use Gunicorn, which is easy to set up. Setting it up may look something like this:

```
gunicorn mirador_django.wsgi:application \
  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
  --workers 4
```

(see : http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html)

I then set a reverse proxy on my web server to point on the Gunicorn. For Nginx the info are on the gunicorn website: http://gunicorn.org/#deployment 
You can also easily set it up on an apache server as I am currently doing.

Hope it can help.